# Fixed background while switching layouts

Tags: java, android, xml

I got my application uploaded and I see that despite I have the same background image on all my layouts.

if I switch, the layout moves according to the animation.

Is there a way for me to set a fixed background for all my layouts?

Does it matter that I `finish();` every layout before I switch to the next one?

Setting the same background to all the layouts doesn't make it fixed (it moves)

neither does creating a style like :

```
<style name="AppTheme.FullBackground" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@mipmap/background</item>
</style>
```

and adding :

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullBackground"
```

to the manifest.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using all activities in your app then change all activities to fragment and just use one activity with your required image as background.

Then use just this activity for all the fragments in your app. This will not move your background image during navigating to different screens(fragments)